# Compass: Why do I need to do a double import for it to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

Using Rails 3.2, compass-rails.

I have the following files:

**screen.css.scss**

```
@import "compass";
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/

@import "screen";

.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 -20px; 
  @include border-radius(6px, 6px);
  @include box-shadow(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

**application.html.erb** (layout, just the relevant line):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

This works fine for my app layout.

Next, for the specific page I'm trying to style (home) I have **home.css.scss**:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps:700);

@import "compass/css3/text-shadow"; <<-- This is the line I don't understand

.welcome {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Oleo Script Swash Caps', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 110pt;
    line-height: 130px;
    @include single-text-shadow;
  }
 }
```

As soon as I drop `@import "compass/css3/text-shadow";`, my code breaks with `Undefined mixin 'single-text-shadow'.` The same thing happens if I move the text-shadow import line into application.css.css.

My question is **why?** I've included the entire compass framework in application.css.css via screen.css.scss. That file is loaded for sure because I see it working. So why do I need to do a double-include like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `home.css.scss` is importing `application.css.scss`, this makes sense as expected behavior. You only need to import it once per compiled document, it will be available to any partials that are included in that document (and come after the import in your code).

It's common to import Compass once into a `_base.scss` partial (along with any other plugins you want available), and then import that partial anywhere you need your base settings.

Comment: But when I render /index, then my entire application CSS is rendered via `application.css.scss` -- meaning, it's already there on the page. And `application.css.scss` already imports Compass. So, why isn't Compass available for `home.css.scss`? I understand `home` doesn't import `application`, but they're both present on the same page at the same time... doesn't that count for anything?

Comment: Pre-processing happens *before* the HTML is ever rendered, so no, it doesn't count for anything. Once they are brought together in index, the Sass has already been processed, and Compass is no longer in play.

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understood your question correctly, but there is no double import here.

compass is a modular framework. you are not forced to use all it's parts. instead you can include only the parts you want. for simplicity, you can also require sub-parts like:

```
# application.sass
@import "compass"
@import "compass/css3/"
@import "compass/utilities/"
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; screen.css.scss above already has `@import "compass"` in it. So... that should import everything, shouldn't it?

Comment: put the main import in the topmost node in your hierarchie. i also don't understand why you require sceen explicitly even if you have a require tree in your application file.