# importing CSS partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I'm using Compass with Rails, and someone [told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864591/compass-why-do-i-need-to-do-a-double-import-for-it-to-work) I should create a `_base.css.scss` partial to include it.

I did it, but I can't help but feel the `@import` is ugly:

```
@import "partials/_base.css.scss";
```

On top of every SCSS file where I'm going to need Compass. Is that the way to go? Is there a shorter/nicer way to specify the filename?

Comment: You can drop the extensions.  Just `@import "partials/_base"` will work (and is usually preferred over specifying the extensions).